# How to Prevent Form from being submitted until Stripe Payment goes through

Tags: node.js, reactjs, forms, stripe-payments, form-submit

I'm trying to submit a form which submits a job post after successfully going through the Stripe Payment checkout.

I had it working with the old version of Firebase 7 but I had to update my code to Firebase 9 and had to work on the logic once again but I can't get it to work now.

**Current Behavior:**

Users click on button to submit form, gets redirected to Stripe checkout(so far so good), however, I just notice the job has been posted already and the user didn't even have to pay.

**Expected Behavior:**

Users click on button to submit form, gets redirected to Stripe checkout. If user makes payment, then job gets posted else it doesn't.

I'm using React and firebase.

JobForm.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Box, Button, Grid, FilledInput, Select, MenuItem, Typography, makeStyles, CircularProgress } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { app, db, storage } from "../firebase/config";
import { ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL, uploadBytesResumable } from "firebase/storage";
import { Editor } from "@tinymce/tinymce-react";
import { collection, addDoc, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";


const JobForm = () => {

    const [jobDetails, setJobDetails] = useState(initState);
    
    const handleChange = (e) => {
       setJobDetails({...jobDetails, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    };


    async function stripePayment() {

        localStorage.setItem("jobDetails", JSON.stringify(jobDetails));
        await axios.post(
             "https://backend-server.io/create-checkout-session",
             { price: "test" }
         ).then((res)=>{
              console.log(res?.data)
              window.location.href = res?.data?.url;
         })
     }

   const handleSubmit = async (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
        await addDoc(collection(db, "jobs"), {
            ...jobDetails,
        })
        navigate("/");
        
   };

    return(
        <>
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                        <FilledInput 
                         onChange={handleChange}  
                         name="title" 
                         value={jobDetails.title}
                         />
                    </Grid>
                <Box>
                    <Typography>*Required Fields</Typography>
                    <Button onClick={stripePayment}
                            variant="contained" 
                            type="submit">Post Job
                    </Button>
 
                </Box>
                </Form>   
           </>
    )
}

export default JobForm;
```

I have reduced the code and removed irrelevant information.

Server.js (Server Code)

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('stripe key');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));


const YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:3000';

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.send('Node Server Working')
})


app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: [
      {
        price: 'price-product',
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/`,
    cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/form`,
  });

  res.send(session);
});


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));`
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: It's recommended to use Webhook and listen to `checkout.session.completed` event to ensure the payment is paid successfully, then allow the job to be posted as the doc described [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#fulfill). With your current code, it doesn't check whether the payment is paid successfully or not and allows job posting immediately.

Comment: Yes, I get the logic, I just can't figure it out. I'll check it out the stripe page as suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write everything in one function, wait for a response from the stripe and, depending on the response, call event.preventDefault();

```
 const handleSubmit = async (e) =>{
localStorage.setItem("jobDetails", JSON.stringify(jobDetails));
await axios.post(
     "https://backend-server.io/create-checkout-session",
     { price: "test" }
 ).then((res)=>{
    if(res.data) {
        await addDoc(collection(db, "jobs"), {
            ...jobDetails,
        })
        navigate("/");
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
 })

return(
    <>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <FilledInput 
                     onChange={handleChange}  
                     name="title" 
                     value={jobDetails.title}
                     />
                </Grid>
            <Box>
                <Typography>*Required Fields</Typography>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </Box>
            </Form>   
       </>
)
```

}